# Updating and Compiling AjaxToolkit Source

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I came across the following issue on my site:
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26978

The solution says to go into the source, make the change, and recompile.  When I download from here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ there is no source, just a DLL, from what I can see.

I also tried downloading and recompiling via NuGet, but the problem remains.

What can I do to solve this issue (as described in the first link)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the "Source code" tab on codeplex and click "Download" button in toolbar.

Comment: Thanks.  After I download and make the fix, how do I recompile to make it work on my web app?

Comment: I have found the file here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d864443e4a38#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/MaskedEdit/MaskedEditBehavior.pre.js so once I edit it, how do I compile my DLL?  Do you happen to know?  Thanks.